# How to create an "Array" of constants

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a number of constants that I'd like to easily be able to access programatically, so I'd prefer to use the notation `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ... instead of `a1`, `a2` so that I don't have to do string concatenation to programatically reference them.

However, I realised that this won't work:

```
SetAttributes[a[2], Constant]
```

I've come to understand that this is because while a is a symbol, a[2] is not, and SetAttributes sets attributes on symbols.

I can do something like this:

```
a[2]=a2
SetAttributes[a2, Constant]
```

But that seems hokey and it's not clear how I could iterate over "a" to SetAttributes in a loop.
I know I can create the symbols programatically using Symbol, but they wouldn't use the index notation.

I thought perhaps `Array[f,10]` would create an array of symbols, but it seems like it rather creates a list consisting of a symbol with different arguments.

I'm a newbie, obviously -- how is this kind of thing done?  Perhaps marking symbols as "Constant" isn't actually that useful?

Comment: `Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] &, 10]` ?

Comment: I've personally never used `SetAttributes[..., Constant]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 and Dan: `SetAttributes[f, Constant]` is really only intended for calculus purposes; it only tells *Mathematica* that differentiating `f` with respect to any other variable should give zero.

Comment: Can you give an example where Array[f,10] fails to do what you need?

Comment: bill s, Doing Array[f,10] doesn't create 10 symbols, so SetAttributes can't be used on what it creates.

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, Constant]` doesn't simply indicate that `f` is a constant. It also indicates that `f[anything]` is a constant. Does this accomplish what you want?

Comment: Note that `Constant` means something very different in *Mathematica* from its meaning in other programming languages. A `Constant` is an unknown quantity that is assumed to be unchanging for the purposes of calculus. It doesn't mean a value that cannot be changed once initialized.